# Python Twisted Authentication Without HTTP Authentication

Tags: python, flask, twisted, flask-login, twisted.web

I'm setting up a Flask server, and want to use a Twisted `ReverseProxyResource` to proxy over another local server. In Flask, I have a `current_user.is_authenticated` boolean which I use to protect pages. How can I lock the `ReverseProxyResource` using this variable, so that it cannot be accessed when a user is logged out? The `twisted.web.guard` module requires me to set up another HTTP authentication system entirely, and the library doesn't seem to have any other built-in solution.

I've set up some demo code, (based off [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36880464/9068081)) attempting to place the Flask server *inside* of the Twisted reactor. I'm using the `ReverseProxyResource` to allow for two-way communication with a Shellinabox server on port 4200.

```
from flask import Flask
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.web.proxy import ReverseProxyResource
from twisted.web.resource import Resource
from twisted.web.server import Site
from twisted.web.wsgi import WSGIResource

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/example')
def index():
    return 'Flask within Twisted?'

flask_site = WSGIResource(reactor, reactor.getThreadPool(), app)

root = Resource()

site_example = ReverseProxyResource('localhost', 4200, b'')
root.putChild(b'ssh', site_example)


reactor.listenTCP(8081, Site(root))
reactor.run()
```

I'd be okay switching to another reverse proxy, but only Twisted has worked so far. I'm also not wanting to switch to the Klein framework due to what I already have established in Flask.

Comment: Why can't you glue twisted.web.guard into whatever it is you use to initialize `is_authenticated` with Flask?

Comment: I'm modifying a [Flask app](https://github.com/duo-labs/py_webauthn) which uses the `login_user` method. How exactly would I "glue" `guard` into it?

Comment: I guess a good step would be to more completely understand how authentication works in your Flask app.  Then you might be able to figure out how to perform that same authentication for other Twisted resources, or at least ask a more pointed question.